# Struggling with build commands in Geany

Tags: java, geany

I recently installed Geany on my Ubuntu machine and I'm looking to compile and run my .java and .class files in specific folders, but I've hit a brick wall. Coming from Windows I set the Compile build command to `javac -d /Home/leon/Documents/classes "%f"` and Execute to `java -cp /Home/leon/Documents/classes "%e"` but I get a "directory not found" error when I try to build a file even though the directory exists. What am I missing?

Comment: `... /Home/leon/Documents/classes/*`? usually it is `/home`, but you may be able to put `~/Documents/classes/*` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `/Home/leon/Documents/classes/*`

Usually it is `/home`, not `/home`, you could also copy the file, and paste it into a text editor to get the path of a file.

You may be able to put `~/Documents/classes/*` instead, as `~` represents `/home/USERNAME`.

Hope this helps [image: smiley]